# Wait for the function to complete and return response then continue with forloop

Tags: android, for-loop, response, wait

I am new to Android development. I am working on sending values from a for loop to printer and I have to wait for the response from the printer to send the next data.
Here is my code:

```
for (int a = 0; a<strings.size();a++) {
  final String ab=strings.get(a);
  String test1 = urat.readSerialData(path); //response from printer
  System.out.println(test1);
  if(test1=="ok"){
    urat.writeData2Serial(ab, path);//send data from printer
  }//then continue to loop                           
}
```

Please guide me regarding this by sharing some reference or help me: how can I do this? 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What issue are you facing? is `writeData2Serial` asynchronous? Does it return anything?

Comment: WriteData2serial does not return anything. I send the string to it for printing. But before that I have to check whether the printer is ready by using "readSerialData". I get a "ok" response from "readSerialData".

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly, you want to wait until `urat.readSerialData(path)` returns `"ok"` so you can send the data to the printer. If that's the case, you should check it in a `while` loop. Something like that:

```
for (int a = 0; a<strings.size();a++) {
  final String ab=strings.get(a);
  String test1 = urat.readSerialData(path); //response from printer

  while(test1!="ok"){
    test1 = urat.readSerialData(path);
    continue;
  }
  urat.writeData2Serial(ab, path);//send data from printer
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is what my problem. I'll check with this.

Answer (score 0):

I have some solution about this, you can use **Thread and Join()** method to wait until your function finish its job

lets see example
-first, add one callback function

```
interface OnComplete {
    void onCompleteCall(String res)
}
```

-after inside loop you should pass this callback coz we need to pass result using interface

```
for (int a = 0; a<strings.size();a++) {
  final String ab=strings.get(a);
  urat.readSerialData(path, new DashboardActivity.OnComplete() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleteCall(String str) {
                System.out.println(str);
                if(str=="ok"){
                   urat.writeData2Serial(ab, path);//send data from printer
                }//then continue to loop   
            }
        }); 

}
```

-We are adding each Thread to List initialize list first and add

```
List<Thread> mList = new ArrayList<>();
```

-your method look like this & add one Thread add performe task under **run()** method.

```
readSerialData(String path, OnComplete onComplete){
     Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Your logic
                onComplete.onCompleteCall("Return your result")
            }
        });
     mList.add(thread);
}
```

-One last we need to start **Thread** so below of upper for loop you can **start** the thread like this

```
for(Thread t :  mList){
            try {
                t.start();
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `while (true)` in `for` loop. The following example you can check a `boolean` value. So, before the boolean is reaching out the for loop will wait, and then you can execute your next method. The boolean method here is `dbcon.insertData` :

```
for( int i= 0 ; i<tallyList.size(); i++){

   
                  String myData=  tallyList.get(i);
                 
              
             while (true){

                      if(dbcon.insertData(myData)){
    
                        // now  do your job here 
                        

                      }else {
                         

                          break;
                      }
              }


}
```

Also note that if `dbcon.insertData` - the boolean value reaching out false the for loop will break. So, you can check your method with a boolean also.

At this point actually, in this method we can execute another two method in for loop 1) a boolean  2) a void.